# How to pass selection from Django template to Class view

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am struggling with something that should be routine for me by now but I have a mental block.
I have a model that stores Country names and a slug version of the name.

Eg. "United States", "united-states"

I want to display the country names in a template for selection, then return the selected country's slug value to the Class based View which will then obtain the data.  The list of countries can be links or dropdown - whatever.  But I need to obtain the selected value in the View.  Here is a simplified version:

Template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<form method="POST">
    {% for country in object_list %}
        <a href="{{country.slug_name}}">{{ country.pretty_name }}</a></br>
    {% endfor %}
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

View

```
class CountryView(TemplateView):
    country_name = THE SLUG
    country_obj = Country(country_name)
    country_obj.build_country_dictionary()
    country_obj.display()
```

So I think I need one of the get methods to access this but I cannot work it out.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "structured way"

Have a look at `FormView`, where you define your form class (which you also need to create, depends on your situation can be a model form as well). The rest is pretty much handled by the view.

https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/4.0/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/

PSEUDO code

```py
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    model = YourModel

class MyFormView(FormView):
    form_class = MyForm

    # depends on what you want to do, you can overwrite form_valid to do your logic
```

The quickest way

PSEUDO code

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <select name="selection">
    {% for country in object_list %}
        <option value="{{ country.slug_name }}">{{ country.pretty_name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit">Submit</input>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

```py
class CountryView(TemplateView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        selection = request.POST.get('selection')
```

Comment: I'll look over the Form Class as an alternative.  Since it was a simple list it seemed a little overkill but I am not getting anywhere the other way.  With your code the server reports an error then shows the csrf token at the bottom shows selection=countryname .  But when I try to display tht name in the post function nothing shows.   Method Not Allowed (POST): /countries/
Method Not Allowed: /countries/
[10/Feb/2022 18:26:42] "POST /countries/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=g4opO8HyxDqfiA5NkCLv2QQmCAkaBpdYe8G5hidDK4bduNO8Esv6vbjt5H7DsiR1&selection=bahrain HTTP/1.1" 405 0

Comment: It's pseudo code only, you will need add `{% csrf_token %}` which I updated in my answer.

Comment: Turns out I had some url clashes mucking up to works .  All good now. Thanks.